# Firebase android get value of object not null but get attributes of object return null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this seems like a rather easy problem to solve but I'm wracking my brains trying to think of what is going wrong. I am trying to query the database for a certain key, and if that key exists I want the value associated with the key. This is my firebase database where the first node is the users did. Before that is the root ref. [image]

I am trying to query for a specific date. This is my code

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    reference.child(FirebaseMethods.getUserUid()).child("Events")
            .orderByKey()
            .equalTo(firebaseDate).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Event event = dataSnapshot.getValue(Event.class);
            boolean isNull = event == null;
            Log.i(TAG,"is null" + isNull);
            Log.i(TAG,"uri " + event.getmImageUrl());
            Log.i(TAG,"date " + event.getmDate());
            //Log.i(TAG,event.getOutfit().)

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

where FirebaseMethods.getUserUid() returns the unique user id. The problem is event is not null but when I try to get the attributes inside event they return me null.

Event.java :

```
public class Event {

private String mDate;
private String mImageUrl;
private Outfit outfit;



public Event() {}


public Event(String mDate, String mImageUrl,Outfit outfit) {
    this.mDate = mDate;
    this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
    this.outfit = outfit;
}

public void setmDate(String mDate) {
    this.mDate = mDate;
}

public void setmImageUrl(String mImageUrl) {
    this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
}

public String getmDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public String getmImageUrl() {
    return mImageUrl;
}


public Outfit getOutfit() {
    return outfit;
}
```

}

Not sure if my querying is the problem ? because when I printed data snapshot it gave me {key = Events, value = {23-08-2018,........} which was the same firebaseDate that I gave it in equal to.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because the Firebase SDK couldn't map the immediate children of the `Events` node (which appear to be formatted date strings) into the fields of the class `Event`.  It's not going to automatically reach into each child node and make assumptions about which one you want (you have at least two formatted date children showing) and how you want them mapped into your class.

Instead, you should consider iterating the snapshot children, then mapping those into Event objects as needed.